# Swift Convert <-> String пропадает месяц

Tags: строки, swift, дата

Доброго времени суток.

При конвертаций из Date в String и обратно пропадает месяц.

```
let date = Date()
let format = DateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "dd.MM.YYYY"
format.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
let str = format.string(from: date) // Из даты в строку
let dad = format.date(from: str) // Из строки в дату
```

Comment: Приводите код текстом с разметкой markdown в вопросе, а не прикрепляйте скриншотом.

Answer (score 1):

С кодом все в порядке, проблема в задании формата.

```
format.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
```

Не забывайте еще указывать локаль:

```
format.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```